# $1+x$ not contained in ideal generated by $x^2+1$ in $Z_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to understand why $1+x$ is not included in $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$, or the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+1$ in $Z_2[x]$.
It’s obvious over the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but I don’t know what makes it just as obvious over $Z_2[x]$.

For example, $x^2+x=x(x+1)$, but this must be even so it ends up being equal to the zero polynomial in $Z_2[x]$. How do I know such a simplification won’t happen to some polynomial multiple of $x^2+1$ that would make it equal to $1+x$?

Comment: $x^2+x$ is not the zero polynomial. It evaluates to zero on the whole of $Z_2$, but it is not the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomials in one variable over an integral domain satisfy the property $$\deg(pq) = \deg(p) + \deg(q)$$
From this, we see that if $P \in (x^2+1)\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ then [since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field] $\deg(P) \neq 0,1$.  In particular, $1+x \not\in (x^2+1)\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

---

Importantly, your example of $x^2 + x$ is not the zero polynomial.  The function $x \mapsto x^2 + x : \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the zero function, but this is not what we mean when we refer to the polynomial $x^2 + x \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now.